# What could oscillate in a system of USB power bank, 5V-12V DC-DC converter and 12V gas alarm?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, oscillation

I bought a 12V gas alarm intended for motorhomes, but I'll be using it at my home. I want the ability to use that gas alarm even during power outages, so I bought a (very cheap) 5V-12V DC-DC converter that converts 5V USB-A (max 3 amps) into 12V cigarette lighter socket (max 1 amp). This allows me to use USB power banks to power this 12V gas alarm that appears to consume 120 milliamperes of current when operating.

However, when I tested this 12V gas alarm with a (very cheap) 5V 2A USB power bank (and the 5V-12V converter obviously), it started to oscillate somehow. The cigarette lighter plug indicator light output was reduced markedly indicating that it probably had power only some of the time, and I could hear a ~kHz range audible sound. The gas alarm never turned fully on. Finally the USB power bank decided to shut off the current completely.

A test with a far more expensive USB power bank was successful, no such problem. I tested four different AC-DC USB power supplies, some as low as 0.8A, some as high as 2A, all of them worked just fine. However, by using a (very cheap) 4xAA emergency charger that turns power from 4 AA batteries into 0.8 A USB power, the oscillation happened again.

At first, I thought that maybe it's possible the gas alarm is intended to be connected to a lead-acid battery, that it could lack capacitors, and that its power usage may be comprised of many very short very strong pulses. So, I thought that a capacitor could maybe smoothen out the pulses, but a raw capacitor connected to a cheap power supply could overload the supply, so I probably need inductor and resistor to limit the current. I started to simulate an R-L-C filter on a computer, and arrived at values of L = 147 µH, C = 330 µF, R = 10 Ohm.

However, before I built the filter on a breadboard, I decided to test something simple. I put the 10 Ohm resistor in series between the 5V-12V DC-DC converter and the gas alarm. Now it worked just fine with even the cheap power bank! No full R-L-C filter needed.

I did some further testing:

- 3.3 Ohm resistor allowed the gas alarm to work
- 1 Ohm resistor too allowed the gas alarm to work

...and finally I only had to wire the 1 Ohm resistor into the power supply of the gas alarm.

What could the cause of the oscillation that was eliminated by the 1 Ohm resistor be?

Comment: Minimum load for proper regulation?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe supply some pics?

Comment: You might want to know that products like this one exist: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09N3LQKDR/

Comment: Can't be minimum load since the 1 Ohm resistor is in series, not in parallel, with the gas alarm. The 0.25 W resistor wouldn't work in parallel since it would create 144 watts then!

Comment: Probably at starting, gas alarm has a 'peak' current need (filament heater).